# Show validation Error beside Fields Javascript

Tags: jquery, validation

I use [Validate.Js](http://rickharrison.github.com/validate.js/) to validate my HTML form using jQuery & it works perfectly. 
But I need to show the errors beside each field, instead it shows a summary of all errors at the top of the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="success_box">All of the fields were successfully validated!</div>
<div class="error_box"></div>

    <form name="example_form">
    <label for="req">Required field:</label>
    <label for="alphanumeric">Alphanumeric field:</label>
    <div id="AlphaNumeric"></div>

    <input name="req" id="req" />
    <input name="alphanumeric" id="alphanumeric" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <label for="password_confirm">Password Confirmation (match password):</label>

    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" />
    <input name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm" type="password" />

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <label for="minlength">Min length field (min. 8 chars):</label>

    <input name="email" id="email" />
    <input name="minlength" id="minlength" />

    <label for="tos_checkbox">Required checkbox (example: Terms of Service)</label>
    <input name="tos_checkbox" id="tos_checkbox" type="checkbox" />

    <button class="button gray" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
    new FormValidator('example_form', [{
    name: 'req',
    display: 'required',    
    rules: 'required'
    }, {
    name: 'alphanumeric',
    rules: 'alpha_numeric'
    }, {
    name: 'password',
    rules: 'required'
    }, {
    name: 'password_confirm',
    display: 'password confirmation',
    rules: 'required|matches[password]'
    }, {
    name: 'email',
    rules: 'valid_email'
    }, {
    name: 'minlength',
    display: 'min length',
    rules: 'min_length[8]'
    }, {
    name: 'tos_checkbox',
    display: 'terms of service',
    rules: 'required'
    }], function(errors, event) {
    var SELECTOR_ERRORS = $('.error_box'),
        SELECTOR_SUCCESS = $('.success_box');

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        SELECTOR_ERRORS.empty();

        for (var i = 0, errorLength = errors.length; i < errorLength; i++) {
            SELECTOR_ERRORS.append(errors[i].message + '<br />');
        }

        SELECTOR_SUCCESS.css({ display: 'none' });
        SELECTOR_ERRORS.fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        SELECTOR_ERRORS.css({ display: 'none' });
        SELECTOR_SUCCESS.fadeIn(200);
    }

    if (event && event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (event) {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
    });
```

Is there a method to change the display style? And are there any better scripts that can do this?

Comment: You will have to modify Validate.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quote:  "But I need to show the errors beside each field, instead it shows a summary of all errors at the top of the page. ... ... Is there a method to change the display style?"

**NO**.  [As per documentation](http://rickharrison.github.com/validate.js/), there is no listed option for how to place the error messages.

Since the plugin's description says, *"Modeled off the CodeIgniter form validation API"*, that tells me that the whole point is to show error messages in a single summary box above the form just like CodeIgniter validation does.  You simply chose the wrong plugin if you want individual error messages next to each field.

> Quote:  "... And are there any better scripts that can do this?"

**YES**. The jQuery Validate plugin is developed by someone from the jQuery team.  There is a huge base of support and tons of options.

> "The plugin is written and maintained by Jörn Zaefferer, a member of
>   the jQuery team, lead developer on the jQuery UI team and maintainer
>   of QUnit. It was started back in the early days of jQuery in 2006, and
>   updated and improved since then."

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/

By default, errors are shown "next to" each field.

**See demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/UGyXP/

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">  
     <input type="text" name="field1" />
     <input type="text" name="field2" />
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I read some bad reviews regarding Jquery Validation, is that true ?

Comment: @SanaJoseph, no, it's not true.  IMO, somebody who was part of the jQuery development team knows what they're doing when writing a jQuery plugin.